# strategies for backing up packages on macosx

Tags: macos, backup, package

I am writing a program that synchronizes files across file systems much like rsync but I'm stuck when it comes to handling packages. These are folders that are identified by the system as containing a coherent set of files. Pages and Numbers can use packages rather than monolithic files, and applications are actually packages for example. My problem is that I want to keep the most recent version and also keep a backup copy. As far as I can see I have two options -

1. I can just treat the whole thing as a regular folder and handle the contents entry by entry.
2. I can look at all the modification dates of all the contents and keep the complete folder tree for the one that has the most recently modified contents.

I was going for (2) and then I found that the iPhoto library is actually stored as a package and that would mean I would copy the whole library (10s, or even 100s of gigabytes) even if only one photograph was altered.

My worry with (1) is that handling the content files individually might break things. I haven't really come up with a good solution that will guarantee that the package will work and won't involved unnecessarily huge backup files in some cases. If it is just iPhoto then I can probably put in a special case, or perhaps change strategy if the package is bigger than some user specified limit.

Packages are surprisingly mysterious, and what the system treats as a package does not seem to be just a matter of setting an extended attribute on a folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you treat the "backup" version. Do you keep two versions of each file (the current and first previous), or two versions of the sync snapshot (i.e. if a file hasn't changed between the last two syncs, you only store one version)?

If it's two versions of the sync, packages shouldn't be a big problem -- just provide a way to restore the "backup" version, which if necessary splices together the changed files from the "backup" with the unchanged files from the current sync. There are some things to watch out for, though: make sure you correctly handle files that're deleted or added between the two snapshots.

If you're storing two versions of each file, things are much more complicated -- you need some way to record which versions of the files within the package "go together". I think in this case I'd be tempted to only store backup versions of files within the package from the last time something within the package changed. So, for example, say you sync a package called preso.key. On the second sync, preso.key/index.apxl.gz and preso.key/splash.png are modified, so the old version of those two files get stored in the backup. On the third sync, preso.key/index.apxl.gz is modified again, so you store a new backup version of it *and remove the backup version of preso.key/splash.png*.

BTW, another way to save space would be hard-linking. If you want to store two "full" versions of a big package without without wasting space, just store one copy of each unchanged file and hard-link it into both backups.

Comment: That's a really useful suggestion. I hadn't though of linking the unaltered bits. It will require quite a bit i

Comment: Of housekeeping to maintain everything but I can do that. Actually I need to keep multiple copies of everything. I never delete anything which is why I can't just use rsync. I have a design goal that the incremental backups are regular files but the linking solution would allow that.